# Installing Bootstrap-4 to Laravel 5.5 using composer

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.5

I created a Laravel project using

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myProject
```

Then I installed Bootstrap-4 using

```
composer require twbs/bootstrap:4.0.0-beta.3
```

My bootstrap dist directory is

```
vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist
```

I copied bootstrap-min.css to public/css directory. Then I added this line in my head tags

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

But Bootstrap-4 is not working on my page. Which file has to be changed now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying composer files directly into your public folder is generally bad practice. Not only is the **public/css** folder in the .gitignore file so it will break when you port over to production, any downloaded updates will not be applied if you update the package.

Laravel News has made a front end preset for Bootstrap 4. Laravel 5.6 will have Bootstrap 4 as a preset option baked in, but for now, this is the way to go https://laravel-news.com/bootstrap-4-laravel-preset/

You could also just use Bootstrap straight from the CDN

Comment: It uses yarn command and it requires npm. I don't want to install it. Can't we find a solution without using npm?

Comment: Composer is generally for your PHP dependencies. You really should use NPM or Yarn for frontend dependency management. Short story, yes, you can do it via composer using dbrumann’s answer below, but he also raises the same concerns.

Answer (score 1):

When you install bootstrap via composer it's put in the vendor/ folder, which is not accessible by your webserver. You have to copy or symlink the css and js into your public/ directory:

```
cp vendor/twbs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css public/css/bootstrap.min.css
cp vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js public/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Since bootstrap is a frontend dependency I would instead use gulp or maybe Symfony's Webpack Encore for managing this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/bootstrap.html

Webpack Encore is a standalone component that should not require any modifications in your laravel appand does not rely on any other Symfony component as far as I know. If that is a concern you have.